# how to select the minimum non-zero number in aggregator transformation informatica?

Tags: oracle11g, informatica-powercenter

I have aggregator transformation already in place. It groups the data on bases of CODE and DISTANCE is arranged in descending order. So the we have to pick the row on the basis of DISTANCE only.Normally aggregator takes the last row as an output. So in CASE 1, it is taking the last row with DISTANCE = 0 as an output, however it has to take the row with minimum non-zero distance which is DISTANCE = 25. It is working fine for case 2 and case 3.
Rule for CASE 2: it will pick the last row which has DISTANCE = 0.
RULE for CASE 3 : it will pick the minimum non-zero DISTANCE which is last row.

**CASE 1**

```
CODE   APP-NO    DISTANCE
A      120         121 
A      124         25 
A      125         0
A      126         0

OUTPUT:
CODE   APP-NO    DISTANCE
A      124         25
```

**CASE 2**

```
CODE   APP-NO    DISTANCE
A      120         0 
A      124         0 
A      125         0
A      126         0

OUTPUT:
CODE   APP-NO    DISTANCE
A      120         0
```

**CASE 3**

```
CODE   APP-NO    DISTANCE
A      120         4 
A      124         3 
A      125         2
A      126         1

OUTPUT:
CODE   APP-NO    DISTANCE
A      126         1
```

Comment: What's the logic behind the expected output? And what query have you got that's working for cases 2 and 3 but failing for case 1?

Comment: I tried the query given by you, however need to test it. Its working fine. In informatica I m using aggregator which is simply grouping the code by descending order of distance and passing th last row as output in all the three cases, however it is sending the wrong output in case 1. Thanks for query.

Answer (score 0):

If you're after the first row that has a non-zero distance or the "first" row where there are 0's for all rows, then this should probably do the trick:

```
with sample_data as (select 'A' code, 120 app_no, 0 distance from dual union all
                     select 'A' code, 124 app_no, 0 distance from dual union all
                     select 'A' code, 125 app_no, 25 distance from dual union all
                     select 'A' code, 126 app_no, 121 distance from dual union all
                     select 'B' code, 120 app_no, 0 distance from dual union all
                     select 'B' code, 124 app_no, 0 distance from dual union all
                     select 'B' code, 125 app_no, 0 distance from dual union all
                     select 'B' code, 126 app_no, 0 distance from dual union all
                     select 'C' code, 120 app_no, 1 distance from dual union all
                     select 'C' code, 124 app_no, 2 distance from dual union all
                     select 'C' code, 125 app_no, 3 distance from dual union all
                     select 'C' code, 126 app_no, 4 distance from dual)
-- end of setting up a subquery that mimics a table with data in it. See SQL below:
select code,
       app_no,
       distance
from   (select code,
               app_no,
               distance,
               row_number() over (partition by code order by distance, app_no) rn1,
               case when distance > 0 
                         then row_number() over (partition by code, case when distance > 0 then code end order by distance, app_no)
                    else null
               end rn2,
               max(distance) over (partition by code) max_distance
        from   sample_data)
where  rn2 = 1
or     (max_distance = 0 and rn1 = 1);

CODE     APP_NO   DISTANCE
---- ---------- ----------
A           125         25
B           120          0
C           120          1
```

---

To display all rows for a given Code where the distance is 0 for all rows (ie. Case 2) instead of just the first row is easy - you just need to get rid of the `and rn1 = 1` from the above query.

So the new query will look something like:

```
with sample_data as (select 'A' code, 120 app_no, 0 distance from dual union all
                     select 'A' code, 124 app_no, 0 distance from dual union all
                     select 'A' code, 125 app_no, 25 distance from dual union all
                     select 'A' code, 126 app_no, 121 distance from dual union all
                     select 'B' code, 120 app_no, 0 distance from dual union all
                     select 'B' code, 124 app_no, 0 distance from dual union all
                     select 'B' code, 125 app_no, 0 distance from dual union all
                     select 'B' code, 126 app_no, 0 distance from dual union all
                     select 'C' code, 120 app_no, 1 distance from dual union all
                     select 'C' code, 124 app_no, 2 distance from dual union all
                     select 'C' code, 125 app_no, 3 distance from dual union all
                     select 'C' code, 126 app_no, 4 distance from dual)
-- end of setting up a subquery that mimics a table with data in it. See SQL below:
select code,
       app_no,
       distance
from   (select code,
               app_no,
               distance,
               case when distance > 0 
                         then row_number() over (partition by code, case when distance > 0 then code end order by distance, app_no)
                    else null
               end rn,
               max(distance) over (partition by code) max_distance
        from   sample_data)
where  rn = 1
or     max_distance = 0;

CODE     APP_NO   DISTANCE
---- ---------- ----------
A           125         25
B           120          0
B           124          0
B           125          0
B           126          0
C           120          1
```

Comment: Thanks Boneist for the query. However value of code could be anything.      We have to make a group on the basis of code and then we have three cases. All the three cases should be achieved within the query.

Comment: Right, which is what I've done. I simply grouped by the code, each one representing a different case. If you were to add `where code = 'A'` to the above query, you'd get case 1 results. If you added `where code = 'B'`, you'd get case 2, etc. In what way does that not match your requirements? Which, by the way, you still haven't explained. I just guessed at what you were after, but really, if you're asking people to help (especially for free), you ought to provide as much info as possible.

Comment: There is a change in the logic, we have to pass the case 2, in which we have all zeros for distance. Then could you suggest the change in the query. Filter should not be applied to this case 2 , all zeros have to passed.

Comment: That's easy - you just need to remove the `and rn1 = 1` from the where clause in the original query. I've updated my answer to include the new version of the query.

Answer (score 0):

This will require two steps: aggregate to get the min non-zero `DISTANCE` and get the corresponding `APP-NO`. So:

In the Aggreator Transformation group by CODE and get the correct `DISTANCE`:

- minNonZeroDist = `MIN(DISTANCE, DISTANCE != 0)`

Now you'll need to prepare a second pipeline with another Aggregator Transformation, group by CODE and get the correct APP-NO. Create two output ports:

- minApp = `MIN(APP-NO)`
- minNonZeroDistAPP = `MIN(APP-NO, DISTANCE != 0)`

and join the two aggregates together.  Create a `Joiner Transformation` with the following ports:

- agg_CODE - link 1st aggregator output CODE
- agg_DISTANCE - link 1st aggregator output DISTANCE
- agg2_CODE - link the CODE from 2nd Aggregator
- agg2_DISTANCE - link the DISTANCE from 2nd Aggregator
- agg2_minApp - link the minApp from 2nd Aggregator
- agg2_minNonZeroDistAPP - link the minNonZeroDistAPP from 2nd Aggregator

Add two join conditions:

- nonagg_CODE = agg_CODE
- nonagg_DISTANCE = agg_DISTANCE

Now use Expression Transformation to pick the right APP-NO using formula like `IIF(ISNULL(agg2_minNonZeroDistAPP), agg2_minApp, agg2_minNonZeroDistAPP )`. That should solve it.

NOTE: Make sure data is sorted on `CODE` and `DISTANCE` and use `Sorted Input` property for Joiner Transformation.

Comment: In this case I would miss the groups of code which has zero distance value. We have three cases.                  Case 1: all non zero value of distance. Output should be min non zero.                       Case 2: some non zero and some zero. Output should be min non zero.  Case 3: all zero distances. Output could be any zero.

Comment: Thanks Maciejg , Let me rephrase my query. CODE   APP-NO    DISTANCE
A      120         0 
A      124         0 
A      125         25
A      126         121

OUTPUT:
CODE   APP-NO    DISTANCE
A      125         25

CASE 2

CODE   APP-NO    DISTANCE
A      120         0 
A      124         0 
A      125         0
A      126         0

OUTPUT:
CODE   APP-NO    DISTANCE
A      120         0 

CASE 3

CODE   APP-NO    DISTANCE
A      120         1 
A      124         2 
A      125         3
A      126         4

OUTPUT:
CODE   APP-NO    DISTANCE
A      120         1

Comment: Honestly, I can't see any difference (after reformatting data from the comment). I still think the above should solve it. Please clearly indicate where the issue is.

Comment: My Apologies for incomplete comment above, please refer to the question , i have added the additional information to it, which would be helpful in reaching upto a solution.

Comment: Ok, since min APPNO doesn't go together with min DISTANCE, it changes the whole thing. Please check my updated response and let me know if there's still anything you'd need covered.

Comment: Suppose for column we have 4 records CODE = A,A,A,A DISTANCE= 45,35,0,0. So after applying minNonZeroDist = MIN(DISTANCE, DISTANCE != 0) Output would be 35 from aggregator and then this will go to joiner which has one input as CODE = A,A,A,A  DISTANCE= 45,35,0,0 THEN result of joiner would be DISTANCE'35'. If all CODE= B,B,B,B DISTANCE=0,0,0,0, then what would be output from aggregator?

Comment: In case of distance =0, as all distance are same,there is other field length,on basis of minimum value of length it take the output.suppose code=b,b,b,b &distance=0,0,0,0 &length=4,3,2,1, so it wll take th last row.I want to know what would be th result of minNonZeroDist=MIN(DISTANCE,DISTANCE!=0).

Comment: I am little confused Maciejg with the use of minNonZeroDist port or it is equal to agg_CODE in aggregator transformation. Or if they are different then how would i use the output of minNonZeroDist. I am new to informatica, please correct me if i am wrong somewhere.

Comment: i can have three ports DISTANCE,NON-ZERODISTANCE,DISTANCE1.NON-ZERODISTANCE=MIN(DISTANCE,DISTANCE!=0), DISTANCE1 (CONDITION: IIF(MAX(DISTANCE)=0, DISTANCE,NONZERODISTANCE). DISTANCE1 would be output. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Edited to include the all-zero DISTANCE scenario. Let me know if you still see any issues.

Comment: One thing I didn't understand,why we are using second transformation here on APP-NO, HOWEVER FILTERING is only based on DISTANCE, if we find the correct distance then app-no would be taken automatically.THE statements I provided above comment will work ??

Comment: What I mean is automatically app-no corresponding to minimum non-zero distance would be taken as grouping is on code. Correct me if I m wrong.

Comment: I'm not able to fully understand what you've got in mind in those last comments. The comments are very limited in functionality. Anyway the second Agg is to get the right APP-NO. We actually need both: min(APP-NO) and min(APP-NO where DISTANCE is not zero) - then we can choose the right one depending on the fact IF there is any APP-NO with non-zero DISTANCE. Give it a try and let me know the results.

Comment: Maciejg, I will try it. One thing i didn't understand, why are we using this.
    minApp = MIN(APP-NO)
    minNonZeroDistAPP = MIN(APP-NO, DISTANCE != 0) . However we have filter the data on the basis of DISTANCE. Why are we finding minimum APP-NO?

Comment: In case where all values for DISTANCE are zero for a group of CODE, result would be taken on the basis of field 'LENGTH', which is arranged in descending order already, so last row would be taken as output from aggregator. Just want to have clear understanding before making any changes.Let me know if you want to ask anything.

Comment: I am doubtful about the second aggregator you included for minApp = MIN(APP-NO). For the case in which all DISTANCE values are zero, why are you using this.

Comment: I put it to get minimum value of APP-NO in case there is no DISTANCE != 0. I'd get null otherwise.

Comment: You mean where all DISTANCE are zero? If its the case, then there is other field 'LENGTH' , that is arranged in descending order. So the last row would be taken automatically. I guess no need to calculate the minimum APP-No.

Comment: Well - I suppose you're right. It's missing in the original question so I wasn't considering this.